# How to identify cause of errors in a Google Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Cloud Function that is using FireStore and Google Sheets API.

In the invocations/seconds chart (see screenshot below) there are some errors but in the logs there are none. 
I also tried to see if the quotas limits was exceeded, but there are so many metrics I couldn't understand how they work.

How can I know what are these errors?
And if it is because of quotas limits, is there a dashboard to easily know which one to increase?

[image]

Comment: You have nothing in the logs? Are you sure to catch and to log all the errors in your code?

Comment: When I click in View Logs, in the top of that page, it only shows debug logs. There are no other logs. It is possible that some code is not catching all errors, but I was expecting all errors shown in that chart to have more details somewhere. Today I got an "out of quote" in the chart, but this one appears in the logs with "quota exceeded".